# FB comments don't update comments count

Tags: facebook, count, comments

I use Facebook comments on my website, and it works fine, but count is updated only after add comment. When i tried remove comment, comment removed, but count didn't update.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=270227116476622";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

```
 <div id="facebook">
                <fb:comments-count href='http://floral-style.ru/blog/novogodnie-kompozicii-v-galeree-butikov-Mon-Plaisir-DEKAPT-Ermenegildo-Zegna'></fb:comments-count>
                <fb:comments width='850' colorscheme='light' href='http://floral-style.ru/blog/novogodnie-kompozicii-v-galeree-butikov-Mon-Plaisir-DEKAPT-Ermenegildo-Zegna' xid='99' order-by="reverse_time"/>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="http://facebook.com">0</div>
```

Replace data-href with your URL.

The "0" zero will be replaced after the server respond.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML - put this after `<body>` tag:

```
<span class='comment-count' id='facebook-comment-count'>
   <fb:comments-count href='YOUR_URL_HERE'/>
</span>
```

JQuery/Javascript - put this before `</body>` tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>       
      $(window).load(function(){
        //UPDATE NUMBER OF COMMENTS
        var comment_callback = function(response) {
            FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("facebook-comment-count"));
        };
        //Call comment_callback function when the comments are created. 
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', comment_callback);
        //Call comment_callback function when the comments are removed.
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', comment_callback);
      });
</script>
```